# Wing panel and dock disappeared elementary os Loki

Tags: release-loki

Both the wing panel and the dock have disappeared.... for some reason non of the keyboard commands work please help me I'm new to Linux

Comment: This started after I updated everything

Comment: Let me know what I need to take screenshots of

Comment: I have had this happen several times. How fresh is your install? Would you be able to reinstall Elementary again without much hassle?

Comment: It's fairly fresh did it last night and in the process of reinstall and everything going good so far

Comment: Bug started after I updated my graphics driver

Comment: Nice. Yeah I have had this happen three times. It seems to be a problem with corrupted .desktop files (the application icons). That is really all I know besides that the only way to fix it is to reinstall.

Comment: Nvidia, Intel, or AMD?

Comment: Intel.    Lenovo idea pad 110

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem with a reinstall

Comment: delete this post